# Тип возвращаемого значения

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который возвращает значение конкретного типа, исходя из указанного параметра (dbObjectType). Если изначально тип возвращаемого значения в методе является object, то когда компилятор дойдет, например до условия c "int", что он вернет, object или int ?
Как можно компактнее переписать этот метод ? т.к предусматривается что типов будет больше.

```
public static object ReturnDBObjectValue(DatabaseObject databaseObject, string dbObjectKey, string dbObjectType)
{
    var dbObjectTypes = new[] {"int", "string", "float", "double"};
    for (var i = 0; i < dbObjectTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        if(dbObjectType != dbObjectTypes[i])
            _errorLog.WriteError("write error type to log");
    }
    if (dbObjectType == null)
        return databaseObject.GetObject(dbObjectKey);

    if (dbObjectType == "int")
        return databaseObject.GetInt(dbObjectKey);
    if (dbObjectType == "string")
        return databaseObject.GetString(dbObjectKey);
    if (dbObjectType == "float")
        return databaseObject.GetFloat(dbObjectKey);
    if (dbObjectType == "double")
        return databaseObject.GetDouble(dbObjectKey);

    return databaseObject.GetObject(dbObjectKey);
}
```

Comment: Вернет верный int, но возвращаемое методом значение будет воспринято как object, для полноценной работы надо будет кастовать его в int.

Comment: @Fike, спасибо, теперь разобрался. Стоит ли использовать generic классы, чтобы освободиться от конструкций if ?

Comment: @Sier, все конструкции, которые могут возвращать конкретный тип, должны возвращать конкретный тип, поэтому - да, лучше через generic. Только я не спец по шарпу и не скажу как в этом случае обойти switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае - конечно генерик.
Но когда вам необходимо передать одно значение из ограниченного множества, лучше использовать `enum` (вместо `string dbObjectType` в вашем случае)

```
enum ObjectType { eInt, eString, eFloat, eDouble }

// В реализации метода:
switch(dbObjectType)
{
...
case ObjectType.eInt:
    return databaseObject.GetInt(dbObjectKey);
...
}
// При вызове:
ClassName.ReturnDBObjectValue(databaseObject, dbObjectKey, ObjectType.eInt);
```

Таким образом, вам не придется создавать массив, проверять ввод =)